# the following c++ program does not compile and is displaying a variety of errors

Tags: c++, c++11

So I was reading about auto and other C++11 std feature and made this program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
using namespace std;
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto create_pair(const T1 &a, const T2 &b)
{

    pair<T1, T2> p(a, b);
    return p;

}
int main()
{
    auto p1 = create_pair(4, 5.6);
    pair<int, float> p(p1);
    cout << get<0>(p);
    cout << endl;
    cout << get<1>(p);
    return 0;

}
```

My question is whether `auto` can be used in the way prescribed here in the `create_pair()` function or there exists some other workaround this to achieve the same result.

The error message when compiled with gcc is this:

> create_pair function uses auto type specifier without return type.

Comment: Ummm... didn't you get the warning message: "`main.cpp:5:42: note: deduced return type only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14`" ? I got it on gcc.

Comment: Perhaps that's just one of the variety of errors alluded to but not seen as worthy of inclusion; an odd choice, to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message fully describes what is going on. In C++11, auto in place of function return type is not return type deduction, but only an alternative way to actually specify the return type, and should be used like this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto create_pair(const T1 &a, const T2 &b) -> std::pair<T1, T2>;
```

It is intended to be used in contexts like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add (T1 const & x1, T1 const & x2) -> decltype(x1 + x2)
{
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

instead of much uglier

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>()) add (T1 const & x1, T1 const & x2)
{
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

In C++11 return type deduction is available only for lambdas:

```
auto create_pair = [](int x, int y){ return std::pair<int, int>(x, y); }
```

Since your function is a template (and generic lambdas allowing to be templated are also C++14 feature), this would not help much.

However, your code should compile under C++14, as the latter brings return type deduction with exactly the same syntax you are using in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic return type deduction is a C++14 feature, and your code would work if compiled with C++14. The `auto` keyword in the return type location is part of the C++11 trailing return type feature, where you specify the return type right before the body with an arrow and the type (e.g., `auto foo() -> int {...}`).

Without macros, the closest you can get in C++11 is a lambda function with a single statement (the return statement) as its body, and this won't work with templates, and can cause slight issues related to the function being a variable instead of a function.

With macros, you can have something to the effect of `auto foo() RETURNS(2)`, which would expand to `auto foo() -> decltype(2) {return 2;}`

On a side note, this function exists already; it is `std::make_pair`, which is implemented a bit more usefully than your version.